# add another array data in array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

hello i am trying to add another array data to an array,
i have array like this,

```
    array:4 [▼
  "data" => array:19 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "a"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "b"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "c"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "d"
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "e"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "f"
      ]
    ]
    
  ]
  "video" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "url" => "x"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "url" => "y"
    ]
  ]
  
]
```

i want array like this

```
array:4 [▼
  "data" => array:19 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "a",
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "b"
      ],
      2 => array:1 [▼
        "url" => "x"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "c"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "d"
      ],
      2 => array:1 [▼
        "url" => "y"
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "e"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "filename" => "f"
      ],
      2 => array:1 [▼
        "url" => "x"
      ]
    ] 
  ]
]
```

i am trying to add array but still no result, is any way to solve this issue in php. please suggest me.

"video" data have only 2 , it will repeated , 1-2-3-1-2-3 on that array.

please suggest me how can i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `array_map`:

```
$urls = $data['video'];

end($urls);

$result = array_map(function ($i) use (&$urls) {
    $i[] = next($urls) ?: reset($urls);
    return $i;
}, $array['data']);
```