# Laravel 8: Target Class Does Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project, and now I wanted to create a route for my resource controller which is named `UsersController`.

So at my route file, I added this route:

```
Route::resource('users', UsersController::class);
```

And because this `UsersController` is placed at `Controllers/Admin` directory, I have added `\Admin` to the namespace at `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::middleware(['web' , 'auth' , 'auth.admin'])
                ->namespace($this->namespace . '\Admin')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
```

But now when I want to go to `/admin/users` url, I get this message:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> **[Admin\UsersController] does not exist.**

So what did I do wrong here? How to fix this error?

As you can see in this pic, the controller is placed correctly at that path:

[image: capture]

I would really appreciate any idea from you guys,

Thanks...

Comment: Do you want all route definitions to have a namespace prefix, to be like how it was before Laravel 8?

Comment: @lagbox Actually I have two custom route files named `home.php` and `admin.php`. And this `admin.php` holds the routes for Admin panel of project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to apply a namespace prefix to that group you can set that prefix:

```
...
->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
->prefix('admin')
...
```

Then for a route in the `admin.php` routes file you can call them like how you would have before:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Comment: can you help me to solve this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403434/add-another-array-data-in-array-php